# Why is VSCode intellisense type hints different for these 2 Django model objects?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-hinting

In the `views.py` after importing the `Video` model I am testing how intellisense works in VScode.

This is the `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Video


# Create your views here.
video1: Video = Video.objects.get(id=1)
video2: Video = Video.objects.filter(id=1).first()
```

this is the `models.py`:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    '''
    info about videos
    '''
    video_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.TextField()
    is_uploaded = models.BooleanField()
    date_uploaded = models.DateField(null=True)
    filename = models.TextField()
    thumbnail_filename = models.TextField()
```

When I start typing I get this for `video1` which is from `video1: Video = Video.objects.get(id=1)`:
[image]

As you can see it offers model fields

but for `video2` which is from `video2: Video = Video.objects.filter(id=1).first()`:
[image]

it doesn't offer model fields.

Why is that and how can we fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one knows that it is getting a single model instance as it is guaranteed by the QuerySet. I *think* the second one is not guaranteed to return a model instance.

In the django source code for this:

```
def first(self):
        """Return the first object of a query or None if no match is found."""
        for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
            return obj
```

so it is returning `Optional[<instance>]` whereas `get()` returns an instance.

Interestingly, `earliest` may work for your usecase, and it is guaranteed to return a model instance as it subcalls `get`.

Comment: yes interesting, earliest worrks normally